# Replace rotted wooden sill of the door?

Tags: door-frame, sill

I think this wooden piece is called sill but not sure, (as seen in the picture below, in red box)
[image: rotted sill of the door]

I am think of replacing it with a new one, the question is, is it standardized? I measured it and the length is 36". Where can I buy it? Anything I need to pay attention to when replacing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a threshold and 36" is a standard size but many places might carry a larger size that has to be cut to fit due to door framing. Your best bet would be to remove it and take it with you to a home store and get a close match, they can vary a small bit in style but the height needs to be the same as it will fit up against your door. I have always caulk around any threshold I've installed just as an added protection against moisture. Good luck